# Bus Timetable database design

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, timetable

I'm trying to design a db to store the timetable for 300 different bus routes, 
Each route has a different number of stops and different times for Monday-Friday, Saturday and Sunday.
I've represented the bus departure times for each route  as follows,
I'm not sure if i should have null values in the table, does this look ok?

```
route,Num,Day,    t1,   t2,   t3,    t4    t5      t6      t7      t8     t9    t10 

117, 1, Monday,   9:00, 9:30, 10:50, 12:00, 14:00  18:00   19:00   null   null   null
117, 2, Monday,   9:03, 9:33, 10:53, 12:03, 14:03  18:03   19:03   null   null   null
117, 3, Monday,   9:06, 9:36, 10:56, 12:06, 14:06  18:06   19:06   null   null   null
117, 4, Monday,   9:09, 9:39, 10:59, 12:09, 14:09  18:09   19:09   null   null   null
.
.
.
117, 20, Monday,   9:39, 10.09, 11:39, 12:39, 14:39  18:39   19:39   null   null   null
119, 1, Monday,   9:00, 9:30, 10:50, 12:00, 14:00  18:00   19:00   20:00  21:00  22:00
119, 2, Monday,   9:03, 9:33, 10:53, 12:03, 14:03  18:03   19:03   20:03  21:03  22:03
119, 3, Monday,   9:06, 9:36, 10:56, 12:06, 14:06  18:06   19:06   20:06  21:06  22:06
119, 4, Monday,   9:09, 9:39, 10:59, 12:09, 14:09  18:09   19:09   20:09  21:09  22:09
.
.
.
119, 37, Monday,   9:49, 9:59, 11:59, 12:59, 14:59  18:59   19:59   20:59  21:59  22:59
139, 1, Sunday,   9:00, 9:30,  20:00  21:00  22:00  null   null     null    null   null  
139, 2, Sunday,   9:03, 9:33,  20:03  21:03  22:03  null   null     null    null   null  
139, 3, Sunday,   9:06, 9:36,  20:06  21:06  22:06  null   null     null    null   null  
139, 4, Sunday,   9:09, 9:39,  20:09  21:09  22:09  null   null     null    null   null  
.
.
.
139, 20, Sunday,   9:49, 9:59, 20:59  21:59  22:59  null   null     null    null   null
```

Comment: @patrickandroid.i have similar kind of question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not look okay.  Each Route/Day/Stop time value should be in a separate row:

```
 Route, Day, Run #, Stop #, Time

 117, Monday, 1, 1, 9:00
 117, Monday, 1, 2, 9:30
 117, Monday, 1, 3, 10:50
 117, Monday, 1, 4, 12:00
 . . . Finish Run #1 . . .
 117, Monday, 2, 1, 9:03
 117, Monday, 2, 2, 9:33
 117, Monday, 2, 3, 10:53
 117, Monday, 2, 4, 12:03
```

etc.

Ideally, you'll have a separate table with Route, Day, Run # in it and assign them to a unique RunID integer value, then use that value in place of the Route, Day, and Run # columns in the StopTimes table.

In general, when you have columns with index numbers at the end (Time1, Time2 or Phone1, Phone2) it's a hint your database is not designed according to the principles of normalization.

Of course, you'll convert the data into the format you suggested for publication.

Comment: @Larry Lusting.i have similar kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

Answer (score 3):

The basics of your system are the bus (or vehicle), the stops (scheduled), and the route similar to the following:

### Bus

bus_id

vehicle_type?

handicap_accessible?

etc...

### Stop

stop_id

location

other_stop_attributes?

### Route

route_id

stop_id

stop_order

I would think you would list all the stops in the route table in the order you want them to occur.  having this seprated allows you to do other route optimization in the future if you want or need to.

You may desire to have a large matrix of Stop to stop distances and times which would give you flexibility in designing new routes.  And lastly, you will want a schedule to tell which bus will be on which route on which day.  all similar to the following examples:

### Stop_Stop

stop_1_id

stop_2_id

distance

time

### Schedule

day_of_week

bus_id

route_id

start_time

Comment: I like idea to store start time from arrival time (start_time + discance) in different tables. Looks pretty good.

Comment: @Randy i have similar kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this problem and I used this :

**Line**
 - number
 - name

**Station**
 - name
 - latitude
 - longitude
 - is_terminal

**Holiday**
 - date
 - description

**Route**
 - line_id
 - from_terminal : station_id
 - to_terminal : station_id

**Route schedule**
 - route_id
 - is_holiday_schedule
 - starting_at

**Route stop**
 - route_id
 - station_id
 - enlapsed_time_from_start : in minutes

Does it looks good for you ?

Comment: I guess for this kind of DataBase we should use NOSQL database such as CouchDB or MongoDB

Comment: @Natim.i have similar kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column