# MYSQL AND query to satisfy on same column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Project Aim :**

We are developing bus timing `Api` where user will search for buses.

Following are my `table structure`

I have following `tables`

**buses**

```
id | bus_name
```

**Description of table:**  Store all buses Names

**routes**

```
id | route_name
```

**Description of table:**  Store All city names

**stops**

```
id | stop_name
```

**Description of table:**  All stop names

**stop_orders**

```
id | route_id | stop_id | stop_order
```

**Description of table:** here i will assign stops for city and stop_order column help to identify which stop next to each other

**bus_timing**

```
id | stop_order_id | bus_id | bus_timing | trip | trip_direction
```

**Description of table:** Here i will assign buses for route stops along with time and trip and direction

**Output Expecting:**

1. When user search between source to destination with time then Api must return all buses list with time
2. if direct buses not there then interconnected buses should show

For example if user search between `stop_8` to `stop_18` with `01:00:00` to `12:00:00` then all buses list with time should show.if direct buses not there to travel between two stops then interconnected link buses list should show

Output what i got is

[PHP compare associative array based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231623/php-compare-associative-array-based-on-condition)

**Present return result issue is**

1. It will return all buses even though if bus is only travel to `stop_8` but not `stop_18`.But my result must return only those buses which will travel between two stops i mean it must fall between both stops .
2. Even i have no idea how to find interconnected buses list
3. When time range is long then there is chance of same bus will travel(trip and direction) multiple times

**Updates**
Still looking for answer .Right now given answer has some points so offered bounty

Comment: update your question and add  the expected  result

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @scaisEdge.i have updated the question

Comment: @vision Can you give some data exemple as well? I think this would help answer the question.

Include result example for the 2 queries.

Comment: Before you provide a bounty you should at the least provide some sample data and your desired result. ... Do you want to see an answer in PostgreSQL, or you want to see the slop that gets the job done in MySQL?

Comment: Why do you mark you answers as chosen, object to the answer and then bounty it all at the same time..

Comment: @evan.at one point of time that answer helped so accepted and looking for more clear solution.any way un accepted now . thanks

Comment: Evan Carol.thanks for the suggestion.first preference to mysql then if ther is no option then postgre sql

Comment: The picture and the table structure doesn't conform. In order to achieve what you ask in the picture, you need to add "city" (best would be to use an ID FK from a new separate "city" table) column in the "stops" table. Or did I missed something? If not, than the solution of what you ask for depends on the change I mentioned above.

Comment: You still haven't given a [mcve]. Make your question self-contained, do not rely on links. Also do not use images/links when you can put text into your question. Also edit your question so that it reads properly from top to bottom, and where possible avoid "updates", just make it as clear and up-to-date as possible. And don't change a question to invalidate an answer, edit it to be best you can with that answer then ask a new question.

Comment: @philipxy.sorry for that i have updated question now .Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: $response=BusTimingModel::join('stop_orders','stop_orders.id','=','bus_timings.stop_order_id') i think the bus_timings.stop_order_id should come first and not the stop_orders.id I have once had a case where the wrong arrangement causes it not to function as expected, secondly try group by

Comment: @Ezekiel.Thanks for the reply i will try

Comment: @Ezekiel.I tried no effect same result

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @EvanCarroll 10.1.19-MariaDB xampp in windows.I can upgrade to latest version if needed

Comment: @vision I'm not going to do this task for any amount of EXP. It would require consulting. You need to represent a graph in the database. One way of doing this is with a Recursive CTE. Without that, you'll never accomplish this on an nd-route. That feature is only available in MariaDB 10.2.2. So you'll need at least that to do this even in theory.

Comment: @EvanCarroll.Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: just provide a good fiddle to play with your data and expected result for any particular case

Comment: @Alex.i tried to create fiddle but its not working .so i uploaded sql file to github.url provided in question . thanks

Answer (score 20):

Because `stop_id` cannot be two different values in the same row.

Aggregation is one way to do what you want:

```
SELECT b.bus_name
FROM buses b JOIN
     route_connect rc
     ON rc.busid = b.id JOIN
     stops s
     ON s.id = rc.stop_id
GROUP BY b.bus_name
HAVING SUM( s.stop_name = 'Sydney' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( s.stop_name = 'Melbourne' ) > 0;
```

This returns buses that have stops with the name of both cities.

Given that buses can have lots of stops, it might be more efficient to do:

```
SELECT b.bus_name
FROM buses b JOIN
     route_connect rc
     ON rc.busid = b.id JOIN
     stops s
     ON s.id = rc.stop_id
WHERE s.stop_name in ('Sydney', 'Melbourne')
GROUP BY b.bus_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.stop_name) = 2;
```

Comment: @Gordon.Thanks works fine .I have one more question suppose if there is no direct  bus to travel from sydney to melborne  how we can show connected buses

Comment: @vision . . . You should ask new questions as new questions, not in comments -- and you shouldn't make fundamental changes to the question after it has been answered.

Comment: .as per your query only first bus detail retirving not all buses which travel between two city .i have asked new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030793/php-mysql-retrieve-data-based-on-two-matching-row-column

Comment: @Gordon.your answer is working when stop name are not repeating but when we add bus timing then it will repeat so result is not as i expected

Comment: @vision you've changed the query Gordon wrote in your answer to remove the `GROUP BY`. Also, if you create an SQL fiddle with sample data, it will substantially reduce the work required for someone to be able to help you, so you might get more answers.

Comment: @fubar.ya thanks for the response. i changed query because if i use group by then it will return only one record so.i iwll try to create sql fiddle.thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @vision I mention the `GROUP BY`, because I think it's removal will give you inaccurate results. Can you not group by `bus_id` and/or a `bus_timing_id`?

Comment: @fubar.the problem in the query occur when user select timing between 1 to 12 then same bus will travel between two city more than once i mean a bus will travel 5 to 6 times so above query will return only one time reocrds not all

Comment: this isn't even close to doing what the op wants, from my reading. But i'm curious why he marked it as a chosen.

Comment: @EvanCarroll.This answer accepted when i asked few weeks ago that time it returned result when i had less records but after adding few more records it went worng

Answer (score 12):

> Also if buses are not directly travel between two city then i need to show inter connected buses.

That's a massive problem in a class of problems called [routing problems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem). For it, you need a better tool: consider migrating or integrating PostgreSQL, and examining [PgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) specifically you'll likely want Dijkstra's Shortest Path. PgRouting runs atop the PostGIS extension.

[Or, consider working on integrating with Esri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142323/what-are-the-limitations-of-using-mysql-with-arcgis).

Alternatively you can [mess around with this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=766), but I wouldn't advise it.

## OQgraph (update)

From symcbean in the comments, you could use the ["OQgraph database engine"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/oqgraph-storage-engine/) to do this too. There is an example of [shortest path here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/oqgraph-examples/).

Comment: @Evan.Thanks for the answer

Comment: Or use the OQgraph database engine with MySQL

Comment: @symcbean I'll be totally honest, I didn't even know that existed. I look forward to seeing its use in an answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll.thanks for the update.is there any idea in php .even your answer has some new valid points thanks for that

Comment: No idea. Google for "Dijkstra, route, php". OQgraph is cool only because it exists: there are 0 questions on dba.stackexchange.com pertaining to it, and the last question on StackOverflow about oqgraph was in April. Hate to be mean, but go learn PostgreSQL. ;) You can pick up the differences (as they pertain to you in a day), and we have whole books on Routing : https://locatepress.com/pgrouting

Comment: @EvanCarroll.thanks for the update.and quick response .

Comment: Not be a hard sell, but you'll never go back to MySQL after you move to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @EvanCarroll.ya thats true.i just gone through the link looks good.hope i will read it and try to do it  .thanks again