# PHP MYSQL retrieve data based on two matching row column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter

I have a table where i need to check or compare two rows two column are equal then only i need to retrieve data

my table structure is

```
id | route_id | stop_id | bus_id | bus_time | trip | direction
```

if i execute following query

```
select routes.route_name,stops.stop_name,buses.bus_name,bus_timings.bus_time,bus_timings.trip,bus_timings.bus_direction from `bus_timings` 
inner join `stop_orders` on `stop_orders`.`id` = `bus_timings`.`stop_order_id` 
inner join `routes` on `stop_orders`.`route_id` = `routes`.`id` 
inner join `stops` on `stop_orders`.`stop_id` = `stops`.`id` 
inner join `buses` on `buses`.`id` = `bus_timings`.`bus_id` 
where `stops`.`stop_name` in ("sydney","melborne")
```

output

```
1 | route_1  | Sydney | bus_1 | 07:05 :00 | 1 |1
2 | route_1 | Melbourne| bus_2 | 07:35:00 |1 |1
```

but in existing query even if bus is not traveling between Sydney also i will get Melbourne result
.
I need to get only buses name which falls or travel between Sydney to Melbourne

Comment: if possible can you show us the sample data? also how would you know a particular bus travels from A to B as you only store stop id which i assume is the start location.is it that way?

Comment: @RohitS.i have updated question

Comment: thank you for updating the question but still the schema isn't clear i mean what does stop_order indicate the next stop? is stop_id is also the route id? is trip_direction is also route_id? just trying to help.. :D

Comment: stop order in the sense when we add stops we cant say we will add in order to db so to identify like suppose one bus will travel in way like a to b to c to d so go on.in db we may not enter in same order like a ,b,c,d so to idenfy route stops in order i have added stop_orders

Comment: What's the difference between a bus and a route?

Comment: @strawberry.here route means city.one city as many buses as well as many bus stops

Comment: @Strawberry. i have updated my question with image

Comment: @RohitS.thanks for your concern. i have updated question with iamge

Comment: We need much more information about the structure of your tables and data. what's the difference between a stop, and stop_order, and how do they relate to bus and bus_timing?

Comment: @TonyChiboucas.Here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

Comment: @vision, would you mind doing the work for us, so we are working on a common data-set? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @TonyChiboucas.I tried to create sql fiddle but its not working when pasted entire sql .so i uploaded sql file to git repository https://github.com/codeforfungit/bustiming

Comment: @TonyChiboucas.Also i never used sql fiddle so i am not aware of that much .sorry for that.

Comment: @vision, here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61767 YOU should have STARTED by building this, carefully, instead of just providing a dump.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas.Thanks for the help.next time i will keep in mind.thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

simple way to do that , without much fuzz , and as u mentioned using PHP, 
so use only one where clause in the query statement and than filter the data using php, 
for example , 
after you retrieve the buses between Sydney and Melbourne, make a  foreach loop and use if condition with selected times.

another way us that if you like using arrays 
match the times in each record using any array search function and get the keys out to another array.
the result array will contain the filtered data with buses between cities and between selected time.