# MYSQL comparing two rows column and return result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have table structure which is explained in my old question

[MYSQL AND query to satisfy on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column)

I have a table where i will add bus timings with stops .For example say if bus A ,B ,C Travel between Sydney to Melbourne then my bus timings table might contain something like

```
id | route_id | stop_id | bus_id | bus_timing | trip | trip_direction
1 | route_1 | Sydney | bus_1 | 07:05:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
2 | route_1 | Sydney | bus_2 | 07:10:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
3 | route_1 | Sydney | bus_3 | 07:15:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
4 | route_1 | Melbourne| bus_1 | 07:20:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
5 | route_1 | Melbourne| bus_2 | 07:25:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
6 | route_1 | Melbourne| bus_3 | 07:30:00 | First_trip | Sydney _to_Melbourne
7 | route_1 | Sydney | bus_1 | 07:50:00 | First_trip |Melbourne_to_Sydney
```

My question is

1)How to retrieve  all buses which travel between two city from Sydney to Melbourne

2) if buses not directly travel between two city then i need to show inter connected buses

Comment: I don’t see any question in the post?

Comment: @Kumar.sorry my mistake. updated question.even i have question and more detail in my old question

Comment: *Sydney *Melbourne

Comment: Please show data which demonstrates the entire problem.  There are no interconnected stops as of right now.

Comment: @kumar.i have old question where i explained in image