# MySQL retrieve data based on two matching row column

Tags: mysql, join

I have following tables

**buses**

```
id | bus_name
```

**stop**

```
id | stop_name
```

**line_route**

```
id | route_name
```

**bus_timing**

```
id | line_route_id | stop_id | bus_id | bus_timing | trip | trip_direction
```

I am trying write a query where i need to retrieve all buses between two stop and between two timings

i tried lots of combination of query but it failed to retrive the expected result

1. i need to retrieve all buses which travel between two city along with between two times.
2. Also if buses are not directly travel between two city then i need to show inter connected buses.

Query,

```
SELECT * FROM bus_timings 
INNER JOIN buses on buses.id=bus_timings.bus_id
INNER JOIN routes ON routes.id=bus_timings.route_id
INNER JOIN stops ON stops.id=bus_timings.stop_id
WHERE stops.stop_name in  ('Sydney', 'Melbourne')
and 
bus_timings.bus_time BETWEEN CAST('09:30:00' AS time) AND CAST('10:00:00' AS time)
```

still buses more than two buses traveling between two city but return only one

```
SELECT * FROM bus_timings 
INNER JOIN buses on buses.id=bus_timings.bus_id
INNER JOIN routes ON routes.id=bus_timings.route_id
INNER JOIN stops ON stops.id=bus_timings.stop_id
WHERE stops.stop_name in  ('Sydney', 'Melbourne')
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT stops.stop_name) = 2
```

still buses more than two buses traveling between two city but return only one

**Updated**
[image]

Image explanation

1. In image city refers to routes table
2. green color shows multiple stops in city
3. city 1 and city 2 will connect in city 3 so if a person wants to go city-1 to city-2 then he need to use interconnected buses between city-1 to city-3 and city-3 to city-2

Updated More Detail
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

**Updated**

My project aim is to store all buses ,lines,stops and bus timing along with trip and direction.
1.There are many routes and each routes have multiple stops and few bus stops may belong to multiple routes
(For example city 1 and city 2 route buses will travel in city 3 routes as per image provided)

2.in bus timing table i will store buses time along with route(line),stops trip and direction(Here trip and direction used because of one buse will travel between source to destination
multiple times a day)

**Output expecting**

1.when user search between source to destination along with the time then application should return all buses travel between source and destination
(if user select long time for example

2 clock to 12 clock )then it should return all buses here there are chances same buses result twice or more than that because every bus will travel
more than twice