# PHP compare associative array based on condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have following output of array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bus_id] => 1
            [stop_order_id] => 14
            [bus_time] => 09:59:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 8
            [stop_orders] => 14
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_8
            [bus_name] => M.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bus_id] => 1
            [stop_order_id] => 22
            [bus_time] => 10:50:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 18
            [stop_orders] => 22
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_18
            [bus_name] => M.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bus_id] => 1
            [stop_order_id] => 22
            [bus_time] => 10:55:00
            [bus_direction] => 2
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 18
            [stop_orders] => 22
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_18
            [bus_name] => M.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [bus_id] => 1
            [stop_order_id] => 14
            [bus_time] => 11:58:00
            [bus_direction] => 2
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 8
            [stop_orders] => 14
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_8
            [bus_name] => M.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [bus_id] => 2
            [stop_order_id] => 14
            [bus_time] => 10:05:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 8
            [stop_orders] => 14
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_8
            [bus_name] => J.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [bus_id] => 2
            [stop_order_id] => 22
            [bus_time] => 10:55:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 18
            [stop_orders] => 22
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_18
            [bus_name] => J.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [bus_id] => 2
            [stop_order_id] => 22
            [bus_time] => 10:58:00
            [bus_direction] => 2
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 1
            [stop_id] => 18
            [stop_orders] => 22
            [route_name] => Sydney
            [seo_url] => sydney
            [stop_name] => stop_18
            [bus_name] => J.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [bus_id] => 5
            [stop_order_id] => 27
            [bus_time] => 11:07:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 2
            [stop_id] => 8
            [stop_orders] => 5
            [route_name] => Melbone
            [seo_url] => Melbone
            [stop_name] => stop_8
            [bus_name] => R.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [bus_id] => 5
            [stop_order_id] => 32
            [bus_time] => 12:50:00
            [bus_direction] => 1
            [trip] => 1
            [created_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => -0001-11-30 00:00:00
            [route_id] => 2
            [stop_id] => 18
            [stop_orders] => 10
            [route_name] => Melbone
            [seo_url] => Melbone
            [stop_name] => stop_18
            [bus_name] => R.S
            [bus_number] => 
            [bus_image] => 
            [bus_stop_start] => 
            [bus_stop_end] => 
        )

)
```

So in this array i am trying to group arrays  based on few condition satisfy 
1) fetch `buses` which as `stop_name=Stop_k` and `stop_name=Stop_s` and `trip` and `bus_direction` must same in both  `stop_name=Stop_k` and `stop_name=Stop_s`

I have tired to make new array but looks like its become complicated for me

```
  $busGroup=[];

        foreach ($response as  $key=>$value){
            if(!in_array($value->bus_name,$busGroup)){
                $busGroup[$value->bus_name][$value->trip][$value->bus_direction][]=$value->toArray();
            }
        }
```

Can any one help me to make it works .Thank you.
Since i tried to get result using query but failed to make it.I had already one question regarding this
[MYSQL AND query to satisfy on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column)

Even if i get same result in query also i am okay with it

Update

my query in laravel

```
$response=BusTimingModel::join('stop_orders','stop_orders.id','=','bus_timings.stop_order_id')
            ->join('routes','stop_orders.route_id','=','routes.id')
            ->join('stops','stop_orders.stop_id','=','stops.id')

            ->join('buses','buses.id','=','bus_timings.bus_id')
            ->whereIn('stops.stop_name',['stop_8', 'Stop_18'])

            ->get();
```

I have tried following query also

```
$response=BusTimingModel::join('stop_orders','bus_timings.stop_order_id','=','stop_orders.id')
            ->join('routes','stop_orders.route_id','=','routes.id')
            ->join('stops','stop_orders.stop_id','=','stops.id')

            ->join('buses','buses.id','=','bus_timings.bus_id')
            ->whereIn('stops.stop_name',['stop_8', 'stop_18'])
            ->havingRaw('bus_timings.bus_time BETWEEN CAST("01:59:00" AS time) AND CAST("12:00:00" AS time)')

            ->get();
```

**Expected Result** 
when user search between source to destination along with the time then application should return all buses travel between source and destination (if user select long time for example

if i speak about array result i need to group by buses based on few condition such as same bus_name must have both `[stop_name] => Stop_8` AND   `[stop_name] => Stop_18` AND `[trip]` and `[bus_direction]` must be same in both `[stop_name] => Stop_8` AND   `[stop_name] => Stop_18`

Updated Question here

Link attached here for sql file

https://github.com/codeforfungit/bustiming

Comment: where are the results come form? i guess they are coming from db.

Comment: @Amin.Ya you are right.i will update my query in question.

Comment: It would be nice if you post an example of an expected result.

Comment: @Laerte.Ya i have updated my question

Comment: what are Stop_k and Stop_s.

Comment: @Amin.that actually user will select source to destination in my example stop_k will be source and stop_s will be destination

Comment: why dont include theme in your query?

Comment: @Amin.I am developing api so need to do it with php itself

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$response=BusTimingModel::
        join('stop_orders','stop_orders.id','=','bus_timings.stop_order_id')
        ->join('routes','stop_orders.route_id','=','routes.id')
        ->join('stops','stop_orders.stop_id','=','stops.id')
        ->join('buses','buses.id','=','bus_timings.bus_id')
        ->where([['trip','=','bus_direction'],['stops.stop_name','=',$Stop_k]])
        ->orWhere([['trip','=','bus_direction'],['stops.stop_name','=',$Stop_s])
        ->get();
```

of course it could be better but for now and while i don't have enough information it's not bad!

Comment: @Amin.Thanks for the effort for anwer.in where condtion i cant hard code bus direction since one bus have multiple trips in a day and every trip will have direction(here direction means melborne to sydney 1 and sydney to melborne 2 it means visa versa)

Comment: @if i remove trip in where condition then i get same result which i posted if you need more detail you can check my previous question.Thank you so much for the effort

Comment: get $Stop_s and $Stop_k form user. it's not hard coding!

Comment: @Amin.Yes you are right but said about trip','=','bus_direction' i cant hard code

Comment: sorry! if i made mistake it corresponds to my insufficient information from your database. any way you can operate on array. although that would be wrong way. in a for loop check if direction = trip and if not unset the member form array.

Comment: @Amin.Its okay.Thanks for your effort

Comment: .here is the link for sql file and detail.https://github.com/codeforfungit/bustiming

Comment: @Amin.I have offered bounty question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164116/mysql-and-query-to-satisfy-on-same-column

Comment: again i think you are using wrong way for saving paths. make use of tree-like structure for saving them.

Comment: @Amin.if you have any idea of sql or php code then can you share

Comment: @vision Yes! I told the idea! each stop is node in graph and connection between nodes will be made by a table. make a table that holds directions with direct_id and path_id columns. make another table with previous_stop_id, next_stop_id, stop_id, path_id. make foreign key between two path_id columns.

Comment: @vision if routes could have overlap my idea could be a bad idea! your implementation was good